# HDMI output with audio only

Tags: audio, debian, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a computer (Debian 7.2 Wheezy GNU/Linux) with two HDMI outputs. I use one of them to address the monitor, another one to address my 5.1 audio receiver.

Now, as the receiver does not have a monitor, I want to send only the audio signal through this HDMI. The problem is, when I disable the receiver video signal in the display settings, the sound gets disabled also. It is selected in PulseAudio, but the receiver does not receive a signal.

When I enable the monitor, everything works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you clone the display to both HDMI ports?  This would enable the audio and sound to be sent to both the monitor and the receiver.  The monitor would throw out the sound, and the receiver would throw out the video.

Another possible solution would be to route your computer monitor through your receiver.  This depends on your receiver having an HDMI out port, but it would work like this.  The computer HDMI goes to the reciever which plays the sound, then the receiver HDMI out would go to the computer monitor which would display the images.  It might introduce a few ms of lag but that might be okay with you.

Comment: thanks for your answer;I tried this solution before, but the problem with it is that my monitor has a super-high resolution of 2560x1440 pixels; the receiver is only able to display a resolution of 1080p so it reduces the signal to it, cuasing the monitor to get a signal error as it cannot use this signal.

Comment: Good point, I didn't actually think about the receiver reducing the output signal.  Your best shot is going to be a designated graphics card.